Kendo UI / JQuery Calendar Widget Template not working and Unexpected Syntax
I am trying to integrate a custom styled (template styled) calendar in KendoUI for JQuery.
While the visuals just don't show up in my application, even if I load the testdate like in the example, (the days would be colored in the way like the example, e.g. month-day < 10 -> orange) I am a bit confused about some of the syntax.
The example is here (under VIEW SOURCE the code tab):
jQuery Calendar Customizing Templates
Why is there a + in front of data.date? Is it necessary?
month: {
      // template for dates in month view
      content: '# if ($.inArray(+data.date, data.dates) != -1) { #' +

Also, in the testdata I don't get the reaseon for use of Pluses:
var today = new Date(),
    events = [
        +new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 8),

Also, do you know the way to instantiate the template on the fly in JavaScript (lets say, after the view has loaded, I want to configure the template to style some specific date in calendar diffferent)
PS The way I implement it is
<div>
    @(Html.Kendo().Calendar()
        .Name("CalendarName")
        .Selectable("multiple"))
</div>

And later in the JavaScript Class, I try to populate it with pre-selected data, and custom styles:
kendoCalendar.setOptions({
    selectable: "multiple",
    disableDates: jsArrayWhichContainsDateObjects,
    dates: dateArray,
    month: {
        content: '# if ($.inArray(data.date, data.dates) != -1) { #' 
    

Thank you
Best regards
